# Python Psycopg2: Multiple columns value updates are not working properly with pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, postgresql

I am trying to update multiple rows of specific columns of a dataframe `df` in postgresql using psycopg2. I have searched over SO and found hints [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47192163/psycopg2-update-multiple-rows-in-a-table-with-values-from-a-tuple-of-tuples) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56749043/how-can-i-update-multiple-columns-on-multiple-rows-in-postgresql-using-psycopg2). But no luck.

Below is my sample `df`:

```
   Bid_Doc_ID   DocumentName      Is_Uploaded           ModifiedDatetime      BidderID
      1          EMD Scan           Y           2021-01-13 13:03:39.938260       325
     -1                             N           2021-01-13 13:03:39.938260       325
     -1                             N           2021-01-13 13:03:39.938260       325
      1          EMD Scan           Y           2021-01-13 13:03:39.938260       326
      1          EMD Scan           Y           2021-01-13 13:03:39.938260       327
      2          Tender Fee         Y           2021-01-13 13:03:39.938260       327
```

Below is the query I am using:

```
sql = """UPDATE table t
         SET "Bid_Doc_ID" = e.Bid_Doc_ID,
         "DocumentName" = e.DocumentName,
         "Is_Uploaded" = e.Is_Uploaded,
         "ModifiedDatetime" = e.ModifiedDatetime
         FROM (VALUES %s) AS e(Bid_Doc_ID,DocumentName,Is_Uploaded,ModifiedDatetime,BidderID)
         WHERE t."BidderID" = e.BidderID ;"""
```

Then I am using the following python codes for pushing data from `df`:

```
tup = list(zip(*map(df.get,df)))  <----this converts the dataframe into a tuple
conn = psycopg2.connect(connection_string)
curr = conn.cursor()
try:
    execute_values(curr,sql,tup)
    conn.commit()
    curr.close()
except (Exception, psycopg2.DatabaseError) as error:
    err = str(error)
    print("Error: %s" % error)
    return err
finally:
    if conn is not None:
        conn.close()
        print('Database connection closed.')
```

After the above piece of code is run, in the DB I do not see the expected result. In fact I am seeing the entire `DocumentName` field is blank, all `Is_Uploaded` is set to 'N' and all `Bid_Doc_ID` is set to -1.

What am I missing here?

Comment: I would add `print(tup)` to see if you are building a correct sequence of sequences to pass to `execute_values`.

Comment: It would also be useful to look a Postgres log when you do this to see what the server is receiving from the client.